# take varibles from post request java

Tags: java

I want to create a microservice that sends messages through a rest of the API. If data is transferred via a POST request, I would like to use this data immediately to send the message. The phone number and other data is currently hard-coded.
How can I use the data directly in a POST request?

```
@PostMapping("/contacts")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createContact (@RequestBody Contact contact)
    {

        String phone_number="xxxxxxxxxxx";
        String customer_phone_number="xxxxxxxxxx";

        open(phone_number,customer_phone_number,custom_uid);
        Contact savedContact = contactRepository.save(contact);

        URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
        .path("/{userName}").buildAndExpand(savedContact.getUserName()).toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

}
```

Can someone help me pls?

Comment: What's inside your contact class? I believe you should have your contact details in there and just use the getters to get them out.

Comment: Isn't this data available to you through the `contact` instance, which is an instance of `@RequestBody`?

Comment: So when I query the data via Get Request, I also get the data out.
However, if I want to query the data immediately in the post request, the data will not be transferred.
I assumed it would work something like this: ```public ResponseEntity<Object> createContact (@RequestBody Contact contact,HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  String phone_number=request.getParameter("phone_number");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int contact_id;

        private String userName;
        private String phone_number;
        private String customer_phone_number;
        private String template;

        public int getContact_id() {
            return contact_id;
        }
        public void setContact_id(int contact_id) {
            this.contact_id = contact_id;
        }
        public  String getPhone_number() {
            return phone_number;
        }
        public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) {
            this.phone_number = phone_number;
        }
        public String getCustomer_phone_number() {
            return customer_phone_number;
        }
        public void setCustomer_phone_number(String customer_phone_number) {
            this.customer_phone_number = customer_phone_number;
        }

        public String getTemplate() {
            return template;
        }
        public void setTemplate(String template) {
            this.template = template;
        }

        public String getUserName() {
            return userName;
        }
        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            this.userName = userName;
        }
        public Contact()
        {

        }
        public Contact(int contact_id,String userName, String phone_number, String customer_phone_number,  String template) {
            super();

            this.contact_id = contact_id;
            this.userName=userName;
            this.phone_number = phone_number;
            this.customer_phone_number = customer_phone_number;

            this.template = template;
        }
```

This is my Contact Class with getters